# swift: TableViewCell doesn't change colors

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

i have a weird bug:
Unfortunatly the app is built rather complicated:
It starts with a "normal viewcontroller" called `RootContainerViewController`.

In it's `viewDidLoad()` it instanstiates a `UIViewController` called InitialViewController using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController` and creates a custom `UINavigationController` using the constructor with the InitialViewController as root.
It then creates an other UIViewController that holds the RootViewController as member.
Finally it calls

```
self.addChildViewController(drawerController!)
view.addSubview(drawerController!.view)
```

while the drawerController does the same with the `RootViewController` in it's `viewDidLoad()`.
The same procedure with other VCs instead of InitialViewController is executed to swap between some ViewControllers.
One of these other viewcontrollers is again a container that instantiates a ViewController called OnePager and adds it as above. This OnePager conatins a ScrollView with a few containerViews each containing a ViewController. One of these has a `UITableView` with TableCells that have a custom class. In the `tableView(cellforRowAt:)` function, the background and font color of 2 of the labels inside the cell are set, which works fine at this time. 
when it is iniated it may not have the data already therefore a reloadData is called on the table after the data is loaded.
But when the users swaps back to InitialView(with the same procedure as at the start) and the again to the OnePager, the colors aren't applied anymore. on some cells the isHidden Variable is set to true and that still works, only the colors don't.
Can anyone help me? it's too much code to copy it in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

I had kinda same problem in collection view

Comment: Happy to help you. Happy coding :)
I am also new to swift, started learning 4months ago, and faced this problem recently.